# sql query behaving differently for different jdk version

Tags: java-8, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a oracle sql date query which works fine for java 7, but when the same query is run for java 8 it is throwing an error as:
"`not a month`".
If I use the query such as:
`DATA_RECEIVED_MOMENT > TO_DATE ('26-09-18 10:33:43 AM', 'dd-mm-yy HH:MI:SS AM')` 
it works in java 8, but for java 7
`DATA_RECEIVED_MOMENT > '26-09-18 10:33:43 AM'`
 even works.
Can someone help in explaining whether the reason behind this is the java version discrepancy, everything else is the same. I have run the query both ways in java 7. working fine.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you have to understand is that *when you write this:*

```
 DATA_RECEIVED_MOMENT > '26-09-18 10:33:43 AM'
```

*You are actually saying this:*

```
DATA_RECEIVED_MOMENT > TO_DATE('26-09-18 10:33:43 AM')
```

Oracle notices that you are comparing a string to a date... so since you are mixing pears and apples, it implicitly calls the *one parameter* TO_DATE sql function.

this one-parameter TO_DATE function uses a default string format which is set **by your client software**: every user session can set the date format it wants. There isn't a fixed default format, since it depends on the language settings of the client you are using (or the server operating system settings, if you are working directly on the server).

In other words: **when your query works with Java 7 you are just being lucky** because possibly the JDBC driver is setting exactly the default string format you are implicitly using.

The date format you are using doesn't even work on my Italian windows client (no need to write a java program: you can try it in SQL plus)

```
SQL>  select 1
  2   from dual
  3   where sysdate > '26-09-18 10:33:43 AM'
  4  /
     where sysdate > '26-09-18 10:33:43 AM'
                     *
 ERRORE alla riga 3:
 ORA-01843: mese non valido
```

and this happens because the default date format initialized for italian client installations is 'DD-MON-RR' (it doesn't even expect the time part)

Here is how to discover your date-time format your session is using.

```
 SQL> select *
   2  from nls_session_parameters
   3  where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
   4  /

 PARAMETER                      VALUE
 ------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
 NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR
```

*you can try this query in a java program to see the different setting between java 8 and java 7.*

this other query on my pc does work:

select 1 from dual where sysdate > '26-set-18'

And notice that "MON" means "first 3 characters of the **name of the month expressed in the language used by the client**".
 So... If I would switch my operating system to english it wouldn't work.

Therefore: you will discover that this is very likely to work in your java 8 applications:

```
 select 1 from dual where sysdate > 'DEC-20-18'
```

but you must be aware that this will work only in PC clients installed in USA using the English language. In England they write the day before the month, for example.

So the good practice is:

1. Use query parameters whenever possible: avoid to write literal values in queries and use 'select * from mytable where date>?'
2. If 1 is not possible, DON'T RELY on implicit conversions from strings to dates or to numbers: always use an explicit twp-parameters call to TO_DATE, indicating the date format (as you did with java 8)

The better option anyway is the first one because it generates less load on the server: oracle keeps a cache of all the queries it has already parsed: if you feed 1000 times the same EXACT query text (even if the parameter values are different), it will lookup in its cache for the already computed execution plan for that text and will retrive the data executing the access plan he has already for that query text *(here I am oversimplifying the thing)*.

But,if you expand the query values within the query text as literal values, you force oracle to re-execute the parsing of the text and the re-evaluation of the execution plan (which can be a very CPU intensive operation) for every execution.. and you also flood the query cache I described before.